# Надо выбрать из матрицы диагональные элементы

Tags: python, математика, numpy, матрицы

Пытаюсь выбрать из матрицы элементы на главной диагонали с тем, чтобы следом реализовать функционал расчета определителя матрицы по формуле:

> `a11*a22*a33 + a12*a23*a31 + a21*a13*a32 - a31*a22*a13 - a12*a21*a33 - a11*a23*a32`.

В результате обхода строк и колонок матрицы получаю ошибку:

> arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

То  есть:

> массивы, используемые в качестве индексов, должны быть целочисленного
> (или логического) типа.

Почитал: пишут, что проблема в пустом массиве; советуют явно в нем задать тип `float` (вроде того: `list_plus_1=np.array([], dtype=float)`), однако не работает. Есть идеи, как записать в пустой список диагональные элементы?

```
import numpy as np
def det(matrix):
    list_plus_1=np.array([])
    for rows in matrix[:,:3]:
        for columns in matrix[rows]:
            if columns == matrix[columns][columns]:
                list_plus_1.append(columns)
                print(list_plus_1)
                
matrix = np.array([[3.8, 6.7, -1.2, 5.2],
                   [6.4, 1.3, -2.7, 3.8],
                   [2.4, -4.5, 3.5, -0.6]])

det(matrix)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def det(matrix):
    list_diag = []
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        list_diag.append(matrix[i][i])
    return list_diag
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
                
matrix = np.array([[3.8, 6.7, -1.2, 5.2],
                   [6.4, 1.3, -2.7, 3.8],
                   [2.4, -4.5, 3.5, -0.6]])
print(np.diag(matrix))
```

> [3.8 1.3 3.5]

`np.diag` может принимать параметры. читайте [документацию](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html).

Comment: Да, хороший вариант. спасибо. Но по требованию задачи - выполнить максимально "вручную", не применяя встроенные методы и функции

Comment: @АлексейКазанцев, а вы почему у себя использовали numpy?

Comment: @АлексейКазанцев Ограничения на использование методов и модулей должны быть отражены в вопросе.

Comment: @strawdog, благодарю за пояснение: согласен. Учту, но замечу: Ваш метод полезен для практики (нет смысла всякий раз изобретать велик): понять же, что за ним стоит помогла задачка.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, стараюсь минимально, хотя отчасти, конечно, беру методы - грешу так сказать. Опять же рассчитать определитель проще простого готовой функцией: я же начал городить огород (в силу задания)

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал вот такой код

```
def det(matrix):
    list_plus_1=[]
    for nrow, row in enumerate(matrix[:,:3]):
        elem = row[nrow]
        list_plus_1.append(elem)
    print(list_plus_1)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]